# Reusing Swift UI LazyVGrid is destroying the frames of grid item

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

I have tow view **FolderView** and **FilesView**

```
struct FoldersView: View {
var folderData : [FolderModel]?

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: SizeConfig.GridLayout.adaptiveGridItemLayout_170) {
            if let foldersObj = folderData, foldersObj.count > 0 {
                ForEach(foldersObj) { folderItem in
                    MakeGridFolders(folderData: folderItem)
                }
            } else {
                CommonViews.WarningText(msg: "No folders are available")
            }
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing, .top], SizeConfig.Spacing.default)
    }
}


struct FilesView: View {
var filesData : [Files]?
var isFolderSpecificFile: Bool = false
var navigationTitle = App.NavigationTitle.entityDetail

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: SizeConfig.GridLayout.adaptiveGridItemLayout_170) {
            if let filesObj = filesData, filesObj.count > 0 {
                ForEach(filesObj, id: \.uid) { fileObj in
                    MakeGridFiles(file: fileObj)
                }
            } else {
                CommonViews.WarningText(msg: "No recent files are uploaded")
            }
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing, .top], SizeConfig.Spacing.default)
    }
    .navigationTitle(navigationTitle)
}
```

While i'm reusing the **FilesView** on tap of folder open all files, everything is working fine but when i go back to original **FilesView** from the tab grids layout are destroyed.

I'm new in SwftUI, not sure what i'm making wrong here.

Attaching video for better understanding[image].

Comment: It might be due to updated related model data, hard to say definitely - needed minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You direction was right, I was getting same data appended every time while switching tab. issue was resolved while removing `@StateObject` and used normal `@sate` and `@binding` approach.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was because of `filesData : [Files]?` is getting appended every time on scroll.

Simple change is replace `@SateObject` with `@State` and @`Binding`

OR

manually avoid appending data on each scroll.

Comment: StateObject, State and Binding have very specific uses. They are not interchangeable... If something can be a StateObject it will usually cause very undesired effects if fit into a State or Binding